# How to find out origin of unknown type

Tags: c#, class, casting

I have a C# function that makes a call to an API. This function returns an untyped object because of reasons.

Now, what I want to do is to cast that object to its actual type. I know what the type is called, but that's about it. Specifically, I can't cast it because I do not know which class I have to import.

So, what I would like to do is this:

```
object drawing = DrawingSoapLoader.GetDrawing(ITEM_NUMBER, REVISION_CODE, DRAWING_TYPE);

if(drawing is CADDrawing){
    CADDrawing cadDrawing = (CADDrawing) drawing;
    [...]
}
```

...however, that does not work because the type `CADDrawing` is not recognized.

Currently, what I have working instead is this:

```
object drawing = DrawingSoapLoader.GetDrawing(ITEM_NUMBER, REVISION_CODE, DRAWING_TYPE);

Type type = drawing.GetType();

Assert.AreEqual("CADDrawing", type.Name);
```

By debugging this, I can see that the type is this:

```
Name = "CADDrawing"
FullName = "CADDrawing"
Assembly = {gd5rgwpt, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null}    System.Reflection.Assembly {System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly}
```

I've also confirmed that the assembly code (here "gd5rgwpt") is different every time I run this.

I can find that .dll in my `\AppData\Local\Temp` folder, and I can even see that it has the CADDrawing type inside, and while I suppose I *could* just copy that .dll and manually add it to my project, somehow I don't think this is the right way to go about this.

Is there a better way to go about this?

Or is this just a case where it would be better to create a local `CADDrawing` class and then cast it to that?

Comment: Sounds like that type is being generated at runtime?

Comment: Given this API doesn't appear to provide public access to the response models, I'd say the best approach would be to wrap the API in your own library that strongly types the responses.

Comment: It's unlikely copying that assembly or creating your own CADDrawing will help. All signs are than class is generated at runtime, and it's different on every run (different assembly). So the question is - how the result of that function is intended to be used? The designers of this api had something in mind when they generated that class dynamically.

Comment: Just as side note: even if the type is unknown, you can still interact with the object using the `dynamic` type (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic). This approach has many disadvantages, but at least it works.